# Add parameter to first post only

Tags: wp-query, youtube, oembed

I've set up a custom post type called "Videos". I have assigned an ACF oEmbed custom field to "Videos".

On the archive page, I have a loop which queries the custom post type and displays all of the videos.

I would like to autoplay only first (latest) video that is posted at the top. The current method I have used (below), adds the autoplay parameter to each post.

Is there a way I can move this parameter to the custom post type query and apply it to the first post only?

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
<?php // Begin main loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php // Query custom post type
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'videos',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
    );
    $get_videos = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $get_videos->have_posts() ) :
    $get_videos->the_post();
?>

<?php // ACF video
    $video = get_field('video_oembed');
    preg_match('/src="(.+?)"/', $video, $matches);
    $src = $matches[1];
    $params = array(
        'showinfo' => 0,
        'autoplay' => 1
    );
    $new_src = add_query_arg($params, $src);
    $video = str_replace($src, $new_src, $video);
    $attributes = 'frameborder="0" scrolling="no"';
    $video = str_replace('></iframe>',''.$attributes.'></iframe>',$video);
    echo '<div class="video">' .$video. '</div>';
?>

<?php // End query custom post type
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php // end main loop
endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: you can use:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/count-items-in-loop?replies=7
to grab the first one and only apply the params to that one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property `current_post` of a `WP_Query` object - it'll be zero for the first post:

```
if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 )
   // First post in main loop

if ( $get_videos->current_post === 0 ) 
   // First video in current videos loop
```